# initializing and getting a radio button value on component

Tags: angular

**Question:** How can I get value of radio input on component initialization in this scenario?

Component:

```
colors = ['red', 'blue'];
selectedColor: FormControl;

ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedColor = new FormControl();
}
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.log(this.selectedColor.value) // return null on component initialazation
}
```

Template:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of colors,  let i = index">
  <input
    [formControl]="selectedColor"
    type="radio"
    name="group"
    [id]="c"
    [value]="c"
    [checked]= "i === 0">
  <label attr.for="{{c}}">{{c}}</label>
</ng-container>
```

Now if I try to get value of checked input in `ngAfterViewChecked()` which is the input that has a `"i === 0"` condition equal to true, I get null on component initialization but it return correct value on radio input changes.

Comment: I'm thinking about the usecase here. A reason for not using ngModel?

Comment: There is no difference both do the same job, but in both situation they need  to get initial value of checked radio input from component first, what I'm trying to do is in opposite direction, I want to get value of checked radio from template to component

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    class="form-control"
    id="'someRandomId'"
    name="'someRandomId'"
    [ngModel]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="changeValue()">
  <label  [attr.for]="'someRandomId'"><span *ngIf="name">{{name}}</span></label>
```